# Volume and height of a pyramid

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, area, volume

[image]

Given the above question. What is the height of the truncated piece. I tried creating similar triangles, one with a base equal to the height of the 5cm equilateral triangle and the other having a base equal to the height of the 8cm equilateral triangle.

From there I worked out the height to be equal to 3.6cm but it doesn't feel right. Could someone let me know if got the correct answer or if my intuition was wrong?

Comment: Your calculation for the height of the truncated pyramid is correct. Can you do the rest?

Comment: Yeh I can, thanks for checking!

Comment: @DavidQuinn What kind of triangle is the one I constructed ( When using similar triangles )? Is it scalene, equilateral or isosceles and how do we know?

Comment: You didn’t show your working so I don’t know, but you just need to use linear ratios (ratio of heights = ratio of bases)

Answer (score 1):

(a) Let the height of the truncated piece be $h$, then using proportion

$ \dfrac{ 6 }{6 + h} = \dfrac{ 5 }{ 8 } $

From which $ 30 + 5 h = 48 $ and $ h = \dfrac{18}{5} = 3.6 $

(b) Volume of top is

$ \dfrac{1}{3} (6) \left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)(5)^2 = \dfrac{25 \sqrt{3}}{2} $

(c) Volume of original pyramid is

$ \left( \dfrac{8}{5} \right)^3 \left( \dfrac{25 \sqrt{3}}{2} \right) = \dfrac{256 \sqrt{3}}{5} $

Comment: Why can we establish the proportion in a) if 6cm is not the height of the triangle (Sloped slightly) with base 5cm? Wouldn't you have to first draw a triangle that goes vertically up before we can use the height of 6cm? I'm a bit confused why we can establish that equation in a)

Comment: Let the lateral edges of the pyramid be along fixed vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ and let the altitude be along the unit  vector $a$.  Take the origin to be at the apex (the top), then the equation of the cutting plane is $ a \cdot (r - t a ) = 0$ .  Let $r = s_1 v_1 $ , then you'll find that $s$ is directly proportional to $t$.  That is, $ s_1 = k_1 t $, similarly if we let $r = s_2 v_2$ then $s_2 = k_2 t $, hence the distance $ s_1 v_1 - s_2 v_2 = t ( k_1 v_1 - k_2 v_2 )$.  Now $ k_1 v_1 - k_2 v_2 $ is a constant vector, therefore, the length of the side is directly proportional to $t$.